# Relative pronoun "whose"

Tags: relative-clauses, possessive-pronouns, whose

[Tait's Edinburgh Magazine, Volume 3, page 637 reads](https://books.google.com/books?id=oKNJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA637&dq=%22on%20whose%20it%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUpNSf4_LSAhUD9WMKHfaEBesQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22on%20whose%20it%22&f=false)

> If he start game on one man's lands, and pursue it to those of
> another, ...it is neither the property of the man on whose lands it started, nor of him on **whose** it is killed, but belongs to the killer...

[image]

> **I.** Interrogative uses (direct and dependent) 1. **what person's**.
>
> https://www.oed.com/oed2/00285120

Is this use grammatical today?

Would it sound better to substitute "of whom" or "what person's" for *whose* here?

Comment: I have edited to provide the full quote. If you are unhappy with the edits you can always roll-back.

Answer (score 2):

Just for clarity, I will say that in this text ***game*** means:

> wild animals and birds that are hunted for food or sport ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/game))

The sentence may seem circumvoluted, but it is perfectly grammatical. I will write between brackets the omitted nouns, and the meaning will become clear.

> If he start game on one man's lands, and pursue it ***[the game]*** to those ***[lands]*** of another, ...it ***[the game]*** is neither the property of the man on whose lands it ***[the game]*** started, nor of him on whose ***[lands]*** it ***[the game]*** is killed, but belongs to the killer...

So the sentence says that

> The game is not the property of the man ***on whose lands*** the game started. The game is not the property of the man ***on whose lands*** the game is killed. It belongs to the killer of the game.

In order to avoid repetition, the second ***the man on whose lands*** was replaced by ***him on whose***.

I don't see why you would want to complicate the sentence even more by replacing that ***whose*** with  "of whom" or "what person's": it is not correct and it would make no sense:

> *nor of him *on of whom* (?) it is killed

> *nor of him *on what person's*(?) it is killed.

***On whose lands*** could be replaced *on the lands **of whom*** but it is extremely rare. I found very few instances on [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+whose+shoulders%2Con+the+shoulders+of+whom%2C+on+whose+lands%2C+on+the+lands+of+whom&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20whose%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20shoulders%20of%20whom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20whose%20lands%3B%2Cc0) with the noun ***shoulders*** (none with ***lands***):

[image]